# Crystal Reports: How do I allow "set to null" when prompting for values to pass to subreports?

Tags: crystal-reports, null, prompt

I have created a report which links into subreports. I created parameter fields to feed into the parameters of the subreports using subreport links.

If I do not add a subreport link and therefore the subreport is prompting for the value directly it will allow the set to null option. However, if the enter value prompt is being generated from the parameter field I inserted then the set to null option is not displayed.

I have 12 subreports so I can't prompt for the same values 12 times.

I am using Crystal Reports XI designer and not .net

Answer (score 1):

set up formulas with nothing in them (null values) to pass to the subreports

Answer (score 0):

In XI, I've only seen the 'Set to Null' option when the report uses a stored procedure as its data source.  Is this the case for your subreport?

Usually, subreports are linked to fields in the main report so that the user isn't prompted repeatedly (once for each time the section that contains the subreport is rendered).  If they are linked, the only prompting that will be encountered it that of main report.

Crystal Reports XI parameter fields (created in the UI, not the result of a SP) do not have a 'Set to Null' option.  As a result, each parameter will need to have some value.

You may want to have a look at my [Crystal Reports: Optional-Multi-Select Parameters](http://www.cogniza.com/blog/?p=29) posting on how you can add some optional values to your parameters.

Comment: Yes I am using a stored procedure which generates the parameters, and Crystal Reports XI. I have created a UI parameter to pass values to the stored procedure parameters within the subreports. The idea is that you can then pass a null to the the stored procedure parameter from the UI one. I have tried setting the edit mask to C and seeing if that works. However I will read over your post on option values.